# Cannot connect to EXO via Exchange PS module using certificate

Tags: powershell, microsoft-office-365

I have setup the necessary prerequisites to connect to Exchange Online via Certificate + Service Principal.

This includes,

- Generating a Self Signed cert
- Creating Service Principal in AzureAD
- Granting Graph Permissions to that SP, and adding to directory role
- Verifying successful service principal auth using the *Sign-Ins* page in AzureAD.

Below is the cmdlet and arguments I am using. I have attempted this out of Azure Automation and my local Powershell.

```
Connect-ExchangeOnline  -AppId c022320e-d5df-44fb-800b-1111111  -CertificateThumbprint '11111111111111111111111111111' -Organization corp.onmicrosoft.com -ShowBanner:$false
```

Regardless of how I call the Certificate or where I run it, I am returned

**New-ExoPSSession : Connecting to remote server outlook.office365.com failed with the following error message : Access is denied.**

Any ideas as to what I am missing?